# fabricjs object.toDataURL() limit

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is there any limit of the toDataURL's size?
On iPad I try to make `toDataURL(options)` and make a new image. But if `options.width` and `options.height` are close to the canvas size, it returns a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any limit of the toDataURL's [data-uri] size ?

Yes, there may be an arbitrary limit on data-URI length in [some browsers (from MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs#Common_problems):

> [...] browsers are not required to support any particular maximum length of
>   data. [...]

What the exact limits are has to be constantly tried out as they may change at any time. The limit is in part due to resource policy (in [particular with mobile devices and some platforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15)), but is also due to security.

A possible work-around is to use `toBlob()` if available for this framework. If not an alternative route can be to access the canvas element directly via the framework (f.ex. via `getContext().canvas`) and call `toBlob()` on that. Some browsers may need a [polyfill for `toBlob()`](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js).